# ruby on rails add div on error messages join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, join

current code for the ajax call:

```
@return = { :error => true, :response => @invitation.errors.full_messages.join("<br />") }
```

the errors now appear as

```
Email can't be blank
Email is invalid
```

how can i add a `div` before the error messages and a `p` tag in each line?

so it would become

```
<div>
    <p>Email can't be blank</p>
    <p>Email is invalid</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could work for you:

```
error_message = content_tag :div, @invitation.errors.full_messages.map {|error| "<p>#{error}</p>"}.join
@return = { :error => true, :response => error_message }
```